# How to change Jabref's copy BibTex context command?

Tags: citing, jabref

In JabRef 2.7, when I right-click an entry, I have the option to copy the cite command `copy \cite{BibTexKey}`. However, as I am working with `biber` I would prefer to have `copy \autocite{BibTexKey}`.

Can I change the settings to copy the way I want?!

[image]

Comment: That I can see, this is not an option in JabRef (although you can customise the data it sends to for example WinEdt). AS such, this really does look like a feature request, which don't fit the Q&A format so well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Joseph Wright suggested in his comments as far as I am aware you cannot modify the behavior from `options>>preferences`. I also do not know of any plug in that would provide this support. I have never written a plug in for JabRef, but you might be able to pretty easily or you could make a feature request to JabREf: http://sourceforge.net/p/jabref/feature-requests/

Comment: Thanks! Actually, there already seems to be a similar request that you can find here http://sourceforge.net/p/jabref/feature-requests/779/